# Server configuration for 1000 concurrent user

Tags: configuration, server

I am developing a web application for which I need some information about server configuration.

Can anybody give me information about server configuration for 1000 concurrent users?

Comment: Look at any site that sells servers. Are they, in any way, marketed based on number of users they can support? No. This should be an indication that just "number of users" isn't a metric that can be used to pick a server.